# How to undo an svn update with staged changes?

Tags: svn, svn-update

I've been removing lots of files from an SVN branch using:

```
svn rm filename
rm -rf filename
```

When I ran svn status, I saw all of the files I deleted listed as deleted and ready to commit. Before committing the changes, I ran svn update. This caused all of the files I deleted to be added back, and they are no longer staged as deleted when I run svn status.

Is there a way to get my deletes back in staging without doing all the work over again?

Comment: Why don't you commit the files you marked as deleted via svn rm ...What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I would like to commit the deletes i made, but I can't commit them anymore because the svn update added them all back. I didn't commit before running svn update.

Comment: Also, you should not need to do an OS rm on the files.

Comment: Yes, I see that now - I guess if you use svn rm it removes the files automatically on commit. By removing them with the OS, I opened it up for update to add them back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately you will not find a solution:
by deleting without using

```
svn rm [filename]
```

Subversion thinks the files were somewhere accidentally vanished. So on your

```
svn update
```

Subversion thankfully recreate these files for you.
Also it totaly forgot what files where recreated. However if you have the output of your svn command, you should see the actions subversion did.